# JS - кроссдоменный запрос любой ценой

Tags: javascript, html

Есть ли вообще способы отправить кроссдоменный запрос на JavaScript?
Может быть как-нибудь через атрибут `src`?
P.S. Мне нужно только тело HTTP - запроса, заголовки трогать не нужно.

Comment: А какие проблемы просто взять и отправить его обычным fetch без любых цен? Опишите задачу и проблемы подробнее, от этого может зависеть ответ

Comment: Заголовок атас! Как название какого-то блокбастера.

Comment: Ну.. Просто отправбте кто через xhr с get

Comment: Есть проблема с cors, то можно или а) запутить chrome с аргументом.. не помню каким, но этом можно найти или б) прогонять запросы через свой сервер

Comment: Нет, если принимающий сервер не разрешает кроссдоменных запросов с вашего домена, то никакая цена не поможет, это невозможно. `<шутка>` разве что заплатите разработчикам всех движков браузеров, что бы они сделали дыру специально для вас!`</шутка>`